How can I create more than one pop-up?
Hope you're all having a nice day :)
I have set up three different buttons (same format) and I want three different popups to show when people click on them. However, only one of them works and I can't seem to figure out why. This is how it's looking so far.
HTML:
<div class="products-bar-container">
                    <div class="products-bar-item">
                        <div class="products-bar-item-title">Terapia<br/>psicológica</div>
                        <div class="products-bar-item-info">...</div>
                        <div class="products-bar-item-button" id="popup-open">Ver más</div>
                        <div class="popup-container" id="popup-container">
                            <div class="popup">
                                <p class="popup-title">Terapia psicológica</p>
                                <p class="popup-info">Durante la terapia psicológica, podrás ir trabajando en ti, estableciendo metas con mi ayuda para que puedas sentirte cómodo contigo mismo. La terapia está estructurada desde el enfoque Cognitivo Conductual, es decir, se trabajan tanto los pensamientos y cómo estos influyen en nuestras emociones y comportamientos.</p>
                                <p class="popup-info popup-list">• Dirigido a: Adolescentes, adultos y adultos mayores.<br/>• Duración: 50 minutos.<br/>• Plataforma: Google Meet</p>
                                <button class="popup-close" id="popup-close">X</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="products-bar-item">
                        <div class="products-bar-item-title">Evaluación<br/>psicológica</div>
                        <div class="products-bar-item-info">...</div>
                        <div class="products-bar-item-button" id="popup-open">Ver más</div>
                        <div class="popup-container" id="popup-container">
                            <div class="popup">
                                <p class="popup-title">Evaluación psicológica</p>
                                <p class="popup-info">BLablabalabalabl</p>
                                <button class="popup-close" id="popup-close">X</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="products-bar-item">
                        <div class="products-bar-item-title">Descarte de<br/>TDAH y Autismo</div>
                        <div class="products-bar-item-info">...</div>
                        <div class="products-bar-item-button" id="popup-open">Ver más</div>
                        <div class="popup-container" id="popup-container">
                            <div class="popup">
                                <p class="popup-title">Descarte de TDAH y Autismo psicológica</p>
                                <p class="popup-info">BLablabalabalabl</p>
                                <button class="popup-close" id="popup-close">X</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

CSS:
.products {
    background-color: #DFF6DF;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;

    &-container {
        display: flex;
        position: absolute;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    &-bar {
        display: flex;
        background-color: #8FCF8F;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        gap: 0.5em;
        padding-right: 3em;

        &-img {
            display: flex;
            width: 30%;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: flex-end;

            img {
                height: 120%;
            }
        }

        &-container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-around;
            width: 60%;
            margin: 1em 4em;
        }

        &-item {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            text-align: center;
            width: 30%;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-items: center;
            height: 60%;

            &-title {
                font-weight: 700;
                color: rgba(16, 51, 16, 1);
            }

            &-button {
                background-color: rgba(16, 51, 16, 1);
                width: 7rem;
                height: 2.5rem;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                padding: 0.8em;
                color: white;
                font-size: 0.8em;
                border-radius: 1em;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        }

    }
}

.popup-container {
    display: flex;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    opacity: 0;
}

.show {
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

.popup {
    background-color: white;
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

    &-close {
        border: none;
        background: transparent;
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1em;
        right: 1.5em;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    &-info {
        margin: 1em 0;
    }

    &-list {
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 2em;
    }
}

.popup-title {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgba(16, 51, 16, 1);
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
  

Javascript:
const open = document.getElementById('popup-open');
const popup_container = document.getElementById('popup-container');
const close = document.getElementById('popup-close');

open.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popup_container.classList.add('show');
});

close.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popup_container.classList.remove('show');
});

I tried copying and pasting the same html to make sure the items are exactly the same, but it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to create a different event on javascript? Let me know if I'm missing any details as it's my first questions here.

You have multiple elements with the same id

@A1rPun Okay, so I'd have to create a different ID for all three popups, basically repeat the process three times in Javascript, right?

Pls correct your nested css link

Since you have multiple elements with the same id popup-open, your JS code only targets one element. Id's should be unique. To have your JS code work for all elements you can use querySelector & querySelectorAll and select by classname like this:


const products = document.querySelectorAll('.products-bar-item');

products.forEach((product) => {
  const open = product.querySelector('.products-bar-item-button');
  const close = product.querySelector('.popup-close');
  const popupContainer = product.querySelector('.popup-container');

  open.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popupContainer.classList.add('show');
  });

  close.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popupContainer.classList.remove('show');
  });
});
.products {
  background-color: #DFF6DF;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  &-container {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  &-bar {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #8FCF8F;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    gap: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 3em;
    &-img {
      display: flex;
      width: 30%;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      img {
        height: 120%;
      }
    }
    &-container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
      width: 60%;
      margin: 1em 4em;
    }
    &-item {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      text-align: center;
      width: 30%;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
      height: 60%;
      &-title {
        font-weight: 700;
        color: rgba(16, 51, 16, 1);
      }
      &-button {
        background-color: rgba(16, 51, 16, 1);
        width: 7rem;
        height: 2.5rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 0.8em;
        color: white;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        border-radius: 1em;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    }
  }
}

.popup-container {
  display: flex;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

.popup {
  background-color: white;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  &-close {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  &-info {
    margin: 1em 0;
  }
  &-list {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 2em;
  }
}

.popup-title {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(16, 51, 16, 1);
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
<div class="products-bar-container">
  <div class="products-bar-item">
    <div class="products-bar-item-title">Terapia<br/>psicológica</div>
    <div class="products-bar-item-info">...</div>
    <div class="products-bar-item-button" id="popup-open">Ver más</div>
    <div class="popup-container" id="popup-container">
      <div class="popup">
        <p class="popup-title">Terapia psicológica</p>
        <p class="popup-info">Durante la terapia psicológica, podrás ir trabajando en ti, estableciendo metas con mi ayuda para que puedas sentirte cómodo contigo mismo. La terapia está estructurada desde el enfoque Cognitivo Conductual, es decir, se trabajan tanto los pensamientos
          y cómo estos influyen en nuestras emociones y comportamientos.</p>
        <p class="popup-info popup-list">• Dirigido a: Adolescentes, adultos y adultos mayores.<br/>• Duración: 50 minutos.<br/>• Plataforma: Google Meet</p>
        <button class="popup-close" id="popup-close">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="products-bar-item">
    <div class="products-bar-item-title">Evaluación<br/>psicológica</div>
    <div class="products-bar-item-info">...</div>
    <div class="products-bar-item-button" id="popup-open">Ver más</div>
    <div class="popup-container" id="popup-container">
      <div class="popup">
        <p class="popup-title">Evaluación psicológica</p>
        <p class="popup-info">BLablabalabalabl</p>
        <button class="popup-close" id="popup-close">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="products-bar-item">
    <div class="products-bar-item-title">Descarte de<br/>TDAH y Autismo</div>
    <div class="products-bar-item-info">...</div>
    <div class="products-bar-item-button" id="popup-open">Ver más</div>
    <div class="popup-container" id="popup-container">
      <div class="popup">
        <p class="popup-title">Descarte de TDAH y Autismo psicológica</p>
        <p class="popup-info">BLablabalabalabl</p>
        <button class="popup-close" id="popup-close">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



